# How to render the changes in view from view model in Xamarin forms

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

I tried several things like adding

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
           {
               Title = TableCategory.name;
           });
```

but didn't work.
my viewmodel looks like this

```
 private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_title != value)
                {
                    _title = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
                }
            }
        }
```

every time I select data from my collectionView below function will set data to Title and what I want is to rendered the data present in Title directly to View.

```
 async Task TableSelected(object obj)
        {
            TableCategory = (TableCategory)obj;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                Title = TableCategory.name;
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", $"{Title}", "Ok");
            });
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

        }
```

My XAML code looks like this:

```
                       Text="{Binding Title,Mode=TwoWay}"
                       HeightRequest="20"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           TextColor="#FF464859" FontSize="Small">
```

What can I try next?

Comment: you appear to be popping the current view off the stack as soon as you set the title?  Which view are you trying to display?

Comment: I have the collection of Expander in Popup page and when ever some one select one option I have cleared the popup instance. I just want to show the data selected from expander to view

Comment: is the same **instance** of the VM used for both the page and the popup?

Comment: yeah both are connected to same VM

Comment: Every thing works fine, only the problem is data stored in Title won't get rendered in the view

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Did you set the BindingContext of the View to ViewModel. Also check that Title property in the ViewModel have the data

Comment: yeah the title property contains data

Comment: Could you show us more information or like jason said post a example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you provided in your question, I don't see any issues.
Check that TableCategory.name and Title in the TableSelected method are different

It seems likely that the values for TableCategory.name/value and Title/_title would be the same after TableSelected, so the UI won't be different.

```
if (_title != value)
{
     _title = value;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
}
```

Please debug the above if (_title != value) condition in your code. Provide a minimal reproducible code sample if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace `Title = TableCategory.name;` with `Title = "HardcodedName";`?

If that works, then something is wrong with `TableCategory.name`.

If that does not work, then remove `await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();`.

---

Important: any code inside of `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` gets executed AFTER method `TableSelected` returns.

What is `PopAsync` supposed to be removing?